# Saving Excel Filename after opening a file

Tags: excel, filenames, vba

In Excel I am writing a macro to move and format data between two files. I begin by opening the first file and running a macro that allows you to choose a file.

I am opening a file using this code:

> myFileName= Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="All Files, *.*", Title:="All Files")

I then follow it with this code:

> Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileName

Later in the code Module, I would like to copy and past things between this newly opened file and the one I ran the macro from inside. Currently I am having to hard code their names like so:

> Windows("data.xlsx").Activate

How can I store the name of the newly opened file in a string and how can I get the name of the excel file I am in into a string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before opening the second workbook assign the name of the current workbook to a variable:

```
nameFirstWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

You already get the name of the second workbook from the open file dialog.